# C# grid layout library similar to Masonry

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I need to create a grid mosaic image from several square images, something similar to what is achievable using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) on client-side.

Is there some .NET library to dinamically create this kind of image, or can you suggest me some basic algorithm to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally created a custom library to create what I need: [ImageGrid lib](https://bitbucket.org/davioooh/imagegrid-lib)

Answer (score 1):

This library seems to have some kind of solver for the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). I think with that keyword you have a good starting point for research into the problem. Out of the top of my head, I do not know any libraries that implement that right away. But I never looked for any.

That is actually a quite fun problem to solve on your own.